# Appnexus-to-Azure data migration error (using sas)

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2

i have a hourly data migration process which copies data from appnexus to Azure using sas key. But suddenly on 6/27/2020, 3:20:11 AM its stopped and started giving error "java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.". Could someone help me to understand what has actually gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what is that you are using to copy the data , let me assume that its some kind of SPARK based system may azure databricks etc . I were you I could have started from the source side and if all looked good could have visted the drivers setup .

Please do share more info on this and we will try to get help.